# how to add text to rectangle in javafx

Tags: javafx

i have small homework with stackpane and gridpane. i build gridpane and small rectangles but when i try to add to text to that rectangles it does not work. thank you for any help.

```
                Text text = new Text(rand1);

                text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                text.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,FontPosture.REGULAR,12));
                text.setX(30);
                text.setY(30);

                Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(x,y,30,30);
                rec.setFill(color);
                stackPane.getChildren().addAll(rec,text);
```

[image]

Comment: Consider using `Label`s instead, which can be styled to have a background color and sized, and then you can simply set their text.

Answer (score 4):

Your code works for me but my guess is that the `text` is being set behind the `Rectangle` try putting `text.toFront();` after you add them to the `StackPane`

In this example I put the code inside a `button` action so you can see how it works but you can just call the action

Runnable Example

```
public class Main extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Text text = new Text("rand1");

        text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        text.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR,12));
        text.setX(30);
        text.setY(30);

        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(10,10,30,30);
        rec.setFill(Color.RED);
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(text, rec);

        //Call the line below in your code 
        //text.toFront();

        Button button = new Button("text.toFront()");
        button.setOnAction(event -> text.toFront());

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(stackPane, button)));
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Doc

```
/**
 * Moves this {@code Node} to the front of its sibling nodes in terms of
 * z-order.  This is accomplished by moving this {@code Node} to the
 * last position in its parent's {@code content} ObservableList.
 * This function has no effect if this {@code Node} is not part of a group.
 */
public void toFront()
```